# Spring Integration Dynamic Selector for JMS messages

Tags: jms, spring-integration, selector, poller

Spring Integration Dynamic Selector for JMS messages

I have a requirement to use dynamic selectors to retrieve messages from the queue. For example i need to get messages from the queue at regular intervals that are > then 1 hr old. It seems the message selector is initialized just once . Can it be changed everytime the poller is used? and how?

Answer (score 0):

With the polled adapter, you can use a [Smart Poller](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#__smart_polling) to change the selector expression before each poll; call `setMessageSelector()` on the `JmsDestinationPollingSource`.

You cannot dynamically change the selector on a message-driven adapter; you have to stop the adapter first.